# php mysqli inserting duplicate value

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a website where you insert radio button data to the database after you click submit button.

However, the problem is that whenever I click the submit button it inserts two duplicate values instead of one.

My code is the following:

```
<form action="test.php" method ="post" >
<b> what is you fav sport ؟ </b> 
</br>
<input type="radio" name="sport1" value="football"> football
<input type="radio" name="sport1" value="basketball"> football
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
mysqli_query($conn, "set names 'utf8'");
?> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  && !empty($_POST)){
    $sport1 = $_POST['sport1'];
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO userTable (user_q1) VALUES ('$sport1')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $SQL);
    if ($conn->query($SQL) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Error: " . $SQL . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
</form>
```

Any help would be be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with *it inserts two duplicate value*? Do you insert two values, or do you insert two rows? The first seems like it can happen, since you named your inputs the same. The second is just weird and shouldn't happen according to your posted code.

Comment: Please define `2 duplicate value` Do you mean 2 rows or one row with both `football` and `basketball` in `user_q1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing the same thing twice 
Just use either

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $SQL) 
//or
$conn->query($SQL)
```

mysqli_query and $conn->query() are used fro same purpose.

just remove any one of the statement, you will get what you need